# Can't use a class as template type in another class?

Tags: c++

I have a class Stack, using template, one of its methods is "push", which is written below:

```
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T _data){
    Node<T>* temp = new Node<T>;
    temp->data = _data;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

The stack works well with `int`, `double`, `string`, `char`....
But it says

```
prog.cpp:32: note: synthesized method ‘Node<Tree>::Node()’ first required here
```

when I use a class "Tree" as data type.
I don't understand, why it works with "string" but not with "Tree", they are both classes, not primitive types.

http://ideone.com/NMxeF
(Ignore the other error, my IDE only gives one error at line 32 and some warnings)

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit after reading the actual code (the "note" shown above is fairly misleading about the real problem).

Looking at the code, where you try to use `new Node<T>;`, that needs a default constructor for T (which in this case is `Tree`) because your Node template contains an instance of T:

```
struct Node {
    T data;    // <--- instance of T, not being initialized in your code.
    Node *next;
};
```

`Tree` doesn't have a default constructor, so that fails (and the note is showing you where the default constructor would be needed).

You have a few choices about how to fix that. The most obvious would be for a `Node` to hold either a pointer or a reference to a `T` instead of containing an actual instance of T.

Another would be to have `Node`'s constructor take a reference to a (probably const) T, and copy that T into the Node:

```
class Node { 
    T data;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node(T const &dat) : data(dat), next(0) {}
};
```

The choice between these two approaches is fairly fundamental. If you have Node store a pointer/reference to T, then it will be the responsibility of calling code to ensure the passed object remains valid as long as the Node exists. The node and calling code will share access to a single instance of T.

By contrast, if you copy the passed object into the Node, then this copy will be destroyed when the `Node` is destroyed. The original T (Tree, in your case) you passed to the Node will remain the responsibility of the calling code, and the `Node` will take responsibility for its copy.

In the *usual* case, you'd tend to favor the latter -- it gives cleaner semantics, and keeps ownership of the data clear. In the case of a Tree, however, you probably don't want to copy an entire tree into a Node if you can avoid it. One compromise position would be to use something like a `Node<shared_ptr<Tree> >` instead. The shared_ptr can keep copying fast and cheap, while avoiding writing a Node that's only suitable for a few kinds of objects and situations. That also makes fairly explicit that you're storing only a pointer that gives shared access to the original object.

Comment: +1 for the nice and thorough explanation for the different options and their implications

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a default constructor for `Tree`?  If not, that might be your problem: Node holds in its `data` member a `Tree` type that must be default constructed when you call `new Node<Tree>`.

To fix, you can modify `Node`'s constructor to take `data` and `next` as a parameter, so you don't require default constructor on its template type (you still need assignment operator to be available).

Comment: I guess I'm not familiar with gcc's notes, but this does not change the validity of my answer

Comment: It is not a "note" (if you refer it to a "warning"), but an error (that causes the program fail to compile) so I definitely need to fix it. Anyway, a defaut constructor for the Tree class is exactly what I missed. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my edited answer -- looking through what he put up on IDEONE, what he posted is only a note, *but* it's related to an actual error, that does need to be fixed before the code can work. My apologies for commenting based only on what's in the question before looking at the actual code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - no prob., I did not look at the ideone code before either :)